# Java Applet Problems - PolicyTool Not Working

Tags: java, applet

I am trying to load an image into my applet with the following source code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.applet.*;


public class plum extends JApplet {
    
    Image img;
    
    
    public void init() {
        img = getImage(getCodeBase(), "waves2.jpg");
    }
    
    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
        g.drawString("I am in the Applet", 35, 15);
        
    }
}
```

I am using the policytool program to try and allow the applet to "read" the jpeg image file and show it in my web browser.

At the moment I receive the following error when trying to execute my applet.
[image: picture of error received because applet cannot read file]

I tried to configure with the policytool but I still receive the same error when running the applet. I set the codebase in the policy tool to the directory my html file is in that launches the applet. I used the `file:///dir/dir1/dir2` type of syntax instead of http:// or https:// for the CodeBase field in the policy tool.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

**UPDATE**

I have configured the `policytool` like so:
[image]

I have also configured it so that the codebase has all the permissions. In either case the picture does not show up, but the error is not thrown. Maybe I fixed it I really do not know. The picture does not show up but the error message is no longer shown saying that there is a permissions problem with reading the file.

Comment: maybe it is the filesystem that denies reading the file? Or add all-permissions to your applet to allow accessing any other files than those coming from the URL where you load the applet from?

Comment: Hi @StefanHegny please see my UPDATE section above. I doubt it is the filesystem denying permission but I could be wrong. Adding all-permissions may work but it is also overkill in my honest opinion. I maybe closer to the solution. This is confusing... Thank-you for the help.